# Ajax request always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax request always return error. I can't figure out whats going wrong with my code.
Here is my ajax call,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Country").on("change", function (e) {

        var countryId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStateList","Account")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { countryId: countryId },
            success: function (item) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(item, function (index, i) {

                    items += '<option value="' + i.Value + '">' + i.Text + '</option>';
                });

                $(".state-list").html(items);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("No state availabe for this country");
                var items = '<option value="' + 0 + '">' + "---" + '</option>';

                $(".state-list").html(items);
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is my server side code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetStateList(int countryId)
        {
            var stateList = UtilityService.StateByCountryForDropdown(countryId).ToList();
            return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And also here is response:
[image]

I also put breakpoints on serverside method while debugging but breakpoints never hit.  I normally call server side method same ways, always works fine but in this case I don't know whats going wrong. 
Please help me out......

Thank you.

Comment: In your error function - put the following parameters error(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) and print these using console.log(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)

Comment: Also what does System out on Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); print ?

Comment: Are you also attempting to send back data via a GET request? Also, can you open up your consoles web developer tools and tell us if there are any blatant errors being shown?

Comment: @user1428716 the out put of console is SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

return window.JSON.parse( data );

Comment: Can you print the output of the server ?

Comment: Since it is not hitting server-side method, I don't understand how to print. But it must return select list of states and here is method

Comment: public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateByCountryForDropdown(int countryid)
        {
            //.Where(x => x.status == 1 && x.country_id == countryid)
            var list = new SelectList(new DataContext().Zones.Where(x => x.country_id == countryid && x.status == 1).Select(x => new { Id = x.id, name = x.name + " | " + x.code }), "Id",
                 "name").ToList();
            list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "---", Value = "0" });
            return list;
        }

Comment: it is hitting server or you wouldn't have a 200 status showing. Inspect the actual request in network tab. Server is not sending back what is expected based on an xml parsing error on a json request

Comment: @charlietfl if you look at above figure of response I dont understand why there is XML and it is showing xml parsing error. I think there should be JSON, since I am returning JSON.

Comment: inspect the actual response body. Guessing there is some server errro being returned or something like that

Comment: Can you please show the network request headers?